# Prove that $h(y)=\int_{y}^{y+1}g(x)dx$ is integrable and $\int_{\mathbb{R}}h\lambda_1=\int_{\mathbb{R}}g\lambda_1$, given that $g$ is integrable.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, lebesgue-integral

We have $g:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, integrable on $\mathbb{R}$

Let's define: $h(y)=\int_{y}^{y+1}g(x)dx$

Prove that $h(y)$ is integrable and $\int_{\mathbb{R}}h\lambda_1=\int_{\mathbb{R}}g\lambda_1$

I have no idea how to do it.

Comment: what is $\lambda_1$?

Comment: @uniquesolution this is 1-dimensional Lebesgue measure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$h$ is integrable if $\int_{\Bbb R} |h(y)| dy < \infty$ so let's have a look und use Fubini to get:

$$
\begin{align*}
\int_{\Bbb R} |h(y)| dy &=  \int_{\Bbb R} \left|\int_{y}^{y+1} g(x) dx\right| dy\\ &\le \int_{\Bbb R} \int_{y}^{y+1} |g(x)|\; dx\; dy \\ &= \int_{\Bbb R} |g(x)| \int_{x-1}^{x}1\; dy\; dx  \\ &= \int_{\Bbb R} |g(x)| dx < \infty
\end{align*}$$

So h is integrable and we can recap the same steps without the absolute value and the estimation to get
$$\int_{\Bbb R} h(y) dy = \int_{\Bbb R} g(x) dx$$

Comment: I do not understand how did you change $y$ for $x$ after step from second to third line.

Comment: Nevermind. I got it.

Comment: Ah indeed there was a missed switch between $dx$ and $dy$… fixed it.